# Magento 2 How to add an attribute like tier price to adminhtml product details editing page?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, tierprice

The tier price attribute is special, it contains a grid of labels, textfields and buttons. I've checked many block files and template files. But I can't locate the related codes. How can I add an attribute like it to the product editing page? Where are the related codes? Thanks.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Comment: Hi did you get any solution? or any helpful link?

Answer (score 0):

The ["row pattern"](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/pattern-library/getting-user-input/row_pattern/row_pattern.html) like described in the Mage 2 documentation is only a pattern guideline, but not a ready-to-use widget, as far as I've been able to find out.

The tier price fields in the product edit page are handled manually via row templates and custom javascript to add/remove rows.

You can see it in this .phtml file:

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\edit\price\tier.phtml
```

These fields must be specially handled in the controller after form submission. I don't think you can create attributes like these, but maybe map them to custom attributes (maybe serialize them).

Comment: Hi did you get any solution? or any helpful link ?

Comment: I did have a solution, but unfortunately I've had a brain stroke a few months ago and cannot use the computer like I did before anymore.

The solution involved, as I've said  in my original answer, appending a new  custom block to the form.. in this block's template, I've created a table with the fields I needed. Each row had a button to eliminate it from the table. There was a single button after the table to add a new row. this is using javascript 

There must be special code to handle the fields upon form submission

Read the row pattern link above to get a better idea

Good luck!